# Can't remove C (no copy on write) attribute on any file

Tags: linux, attr, btrfs

so for years now I've been using btrfs without any issues, up until recently when I noticed all of my new files seem to have a +C attributes, there is some that do not, I've been unable to figure out what causes file attribute to have +C

under my understanding, if I run:

```
chattr -C file
```

it should remove the C attribute, but not even with sudo that command seems to do anything, altho I can add/remove other attributes, just not C.

I assumed it could be to fstab but seems to be good, i even added datacow at the end

```
UUID=ed0d0921-a6cd-48c0-ab59-27b7b7e8bdd2 /home/jawz/Misc/HD btrfs defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,commit=120,compress=zstd,datacow 0 0
```

Is there any way that I can fix my filesystem so the files can be copy on write again?

Comment: FYI, this isn't really the best Stack Exchange site to post this question since Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  This question will likely be closed because of this.  Have a look at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/btrfs) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/btrfs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [btrfs wiki FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_copy-on-write_be_turned_off_for_data_blocks.3F):

> ... the COW status can be modified only for empty or newly created files.

If you really need to change the COW status, I suppose you will need to copy your current files to new files.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that, yeah made a quick script to move the files from one hard drive mount to another and then move them back, thanks for pointing me on the right direction!